# Near which points of S is S the graph of a function y = f(x)? x = f(y)?

Tags: calculus

$S = \{(x,y):F(x,y) = 0\}$ where F(x,y) = $x^2+3y^2-3$.

I know the following theorem.

Let $F$ be a real-valued function of class $C_1$ on an open set in $\mathbb R^2$, and let $S =
\{(x, y) : F(x, y)=0\}$. If $a\in S$ and $\nabla F(a) \neq 0$, there is a neighborhood $N$ of a in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $S \cap N$ is the graph of a $C_1$ function $f$ (either $y = f(x)$ or
$x = f(y)$).

So, $\nabla F = [2x,6y]$ and equals to zero at $(0,0)$ only. Therefore, for any point in $S$ I should be able to graph $S$ as $y = f(x)$ or $x=f(y)$ because of the fact $(0,0)$ is not in $S$ and theorem.

But solution manual of my book says that $y=f(x)$ at any point except $(\pm\sqrt 3 ,0)$ and $x=f(y)$ at any point except $(0,\pm\sqrt 1)$. I really don't understand why those points are not included.

Comment: Are you sure that's the theorem you're given? You may be confusing the inverse function theorem and the implicit function theorem.